# Tabs for Excel navigation

Tags: microsoft-excel

I downloaded this add-in: [Tabs for Excel](https://www.extendoffice.com/product/excel-workbooks-tabs.html)

The navigation arrow is drop down menu.

[image]

How do I change it to left right navigation.

[image]

Comment: You're asking for help with a specific plugin... I would have though asking the company/dev who creates the software would be the *better* place to ask. I suspect Excel can't do anything and the functionality you require will need to be added to the plugin. https://www.extendoffice.com/support/about-us.html

Comment: I guess the down vote is due to question being off topic. I don't think it deserves a downvote, the question is clear, well worded and even has pictures. However, I guess this means some members feel this question is off topic